# VBA Login sage50

Tags: vba, passwords, connect, sage50

I connect to sage50 with VBA code and the application starts - no problem. But then the system aks to put in username and password. How do I subbmit this values by VBA code?

I connect sage50 like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub StartSage50()
    Dim MyAppID
    ' --- Start sage50
    MyAppID = Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Sage\Sage50\Lohn\Sage50Lohn.exe", 1) 

' -

End Sub
```

Comment: To programmatically interact with the Sage session you need to hook up with the object model; there's no need to actually launch Sage itself.

Comment: Hi Mathieu, I'm a VBA beginner and I apologize if I ask such simple, maybe even stupid questions. In any case, thank you very much for your patience and your valuable support. I will try to implement your instructions as good as I understand them. But in general: I did a basic training for VBA, but all these special commands, where can I find them? Is there a way to find or learn them somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if Sage50 uses the same COM API Sage 300 uses, but if it does you'll want to add a reference to the `AccpacCOMAPI` type library.

To connect to Sage, you need to create an `AccpacSession` object:

```
Dim session As AccpacCOMAPI.AccpacSession
Set session = New AccpacCOMAPI.AccpacSession
```

Then you need to invoke its `Init` method:

```
'Application ID "XY" is reserved for non-SDK applications to use.
Const NonSDKAppId As String = "XY"
Const ProgramName As String = NonSDKAppId & "9999"
Const AppVersion As String = "01A"

session.Init vbNullString, NonSDKAppId, ProgramName, AppVersion
```

From there you can get the available *organizations* (Sage databases) like this:

```
Dim orgs As Collection
Set orgs = New Collection

Dim index As Long
Dim org As AccpacCOMAPI.AccpacOrganization

For index = 0 To session.Organizations.Count - 1
    With session.Organizations.ItemByIndex(index)
        If .Type = AccpacCOMAPI.ORG_COMPANY Then orgs.Add Array(.DatabaseID, .Name)
    End with
Next

ReDim organizations(0 To orgs.Count - 1, 0 To 1)
Dim itemIndex As Long
Dim item As Variant
For Each item In orgs
    organizations(itemIndex, 0) = item(0)
    organizations(itemIndex, 1) = item(1)
    itemIndex = itemIndex + 1
Next
```

And now you have an `organizations` 2D array that contains the database ID in one column, and the description in another - which is perfect for populating a 2-column dropdown/combobox on a custom login form, if you want one. Otherwise you can just hard-code your credentials when you `Open` the session:

```
session.Open "username", "password", "database ID", VBA.DateTime.Now, 0, vbNullString
```

And the last & final step is to open the `DbLink`:

```
Dim dblink As AccpacCOMAPI.AccpacDBLink
Set dblink = session.OpenDBLink(AccpacCOMAPI.DBLINK_COMPANY, AccpacCOMAPI.DBLINK_FLG_READWRITE)
```

And from there, you're good to go!

```
Debug.Assert session.IsOpened '<~ should be true now
```